# How can I do grouped boxplots with ggplot?

Tags: r

I am trying to create paired boxplots in R, but unfortunately, it is not working: I would like to have two boxplots for station 1 (day and night) and the same for station 2. Between Station 1 and 2 should be a small gap. I know that it is a really simple question, but I can't find a good code on the internet.

I hope that someone can help me. Thanks!
This is my data:

```
structure(list(Station = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = c("night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day"), date = c("01.12.2018", 
"02.12.2018", "03.12.2018", "04.12.2018", "05.12.2018", "06.12.2018", 
"07.12.2018", "08.12.2018", "09.12.2018", "10.12.2018", "11.12.2018", 
"12.12.2018", "13.12.2018", "14.12.2018", "15.12.2018", "16.12.2018", 
"17.12.2018", "18.12.2018", "19.12.2018", "20.12.2018", "21.12.2018", 
"22.12.2018", "23.12.2018", "24.12.2018", "25.12.2018", "26.12.2018", 
"27.12.2018", "28.12.2018", "29.12.2018", "30.12.2018", "31.12.2018", 
"01.01.2019", "02.01.2019", "03.01.2019", "04.01.2019", "01.12.2018", 
"02.12.2018", "03.12.2018", "04.12.2018", "05.12.2018", "06.12.2018", 
"07.12.2018", "08.12.2018", "09.12.2018", "10.12.2018", "11.12.2018", 
"12.12.2018", "13.12.2018", "14.12.2018", "15.12.2018", "16.12.2018", 
"17.12.2018", "18.12.2018", "19.12.2018", "20.12.2018", "21.12.2018", 
"22.12.2018", "23.12.2018", "24.12.2018", "25.12.2018", "26.12.2018", 
"27.12.2018", "28.12.2018", "29.12.2018", "30.12.2018", "31.12.2018", 
"01.01.2019", "02.01.2019", "03.01.2019", "04.01.2019", "01.12.2018", 
"02.12.2018", "03.12.2018", "04.12.2018", "05.12.2018", "06.12.2018", 
"07.12.2018", "08.12.2018", "09.12.2018", "10.12.2018", "11.12.2018", 
"12.12.2018", "13.12.2018", "14.12.2018", "15.12.2018", "16.12.2018", 
"17.12.2018", "18.12.2018", "19.12.2018", "20.12.2018", "21.12.2018", 
"22.12.2018", "23.12.2018", "24.12.2018", "01.12.2018", "02.12.2018", 
"03.12.2018", "04.12.2018", "05.12.2018", "06.12.2018", "07.12.2018", 
"08.12.2018", "09.12.2018", "10.12.2018", "11.12.2018", "12.12.2018", 
"13.12.2018", "14.12.2018", "15.12.2018", "16.12.2018", "17.12.2018", 
"18.12.2018", "19.12.2018", "20.12.2018", "21.12.2018", "22.12.2018", 
"23.12.2018", "24.12.2018"), number = c(0, 0.126103405, 0.25, 
0, 0, 0, 0.606060606, 0, 0.238663484, 0, 0.117233294, 0.23255814, 
1.156069364, 1.26146789, 9.886363636, 0.789177001, 6.047032475, 
6.651884701, 1.321585903, 1.092896175, 0.433369447, 0.215053763, 
0.640341515, 2.010582011, 2.415966387, 1.774530271, 0.414507772, 
0.513874615, 0.714285714, 0.20242915, 0.201005025, 1.994017946, 
1.287128713, 0.68762279, 0, 0.161725067, 0.124481328, 0.25, 0.188284519, 
0.062959077, 0, 0, 0.446333688, 0.256136606, 0.321888412, 0.193965517, 
0.064935065, 0.260586319, 0.392584515, 0.211267606, 0.066079295, 
0.663716814, 1.134593993, 0.067039106, 0.336700337, 0.135440181, 
0.884353741, 0.341685649, 0.756013746, 2.002301496, 1.456647399, 
1.81184669, 2.453271028, 0.352112676, 2.691853601, 2.206405694, 
2.577565632, 2.661870504, 2.171290712, 2.717391304, 0.127064803, 
0, 0.25, 0.123915737, 0.789177001, 6.047032475, 6.651884701, 
1.321585903, 0.327868852, 1.300108342, 0.64516129, 1.814300961, 
0.634920635, 2.415966387, 0.521920668, 0.725388601, 0.205549846, 
0.612244898, 1.012145749, 0.100502513, 1.395812562, 0.792079208, 
1.178781925, 0, 0.174672489, 0.373443983, 0.25, 1.380753138, 
0.769230769, 0.663716814, 1.134593993, 0.067039106, 0.336700337, 
0.338600451, 0.612244898, 0.273348519, 0.343642612, 1.242807825, 
1.040462428, 0.487804878, 0.911214953, 0.281690141, 0.920897285, 
1.28113879, 1.718377088, 2.877697842, 0.579010856, 2.95620438
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -118L))
```

Code Used:

```
#input1 <- "C:\\Users\\test.csv" test <- read.csv(input1, sep=";") 
#dput(test) 
test$date = as.Date(test$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y") 
library(ggplot2) 
plot <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Station, group=time, y = number)) + geom_boxplot() 
print(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test %>% 
  mutate(date=dmy(date),Station=as.factor(Station),time=as.factor(time)) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Station, y = number)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

**BONUS:**

```
test %>% 
  mutate(date=dmy(date),Station=as.factor(Station),time=as.factor(time)) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Station, y = number,fill=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it is not working. It shows me the errror: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Could you show me the code you used? BTW I thought of renaming `time`. The data is before modifying. That is all the modifications are done in this code. Specifically this: `as.Date(test$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")` is done using `lubridate(dmy)`

Comment: Sure. This is my code: input1 <- "C:\\Users\\test.csv"

test <- read.csv(input1, sep=";") 
test$date = as.Date(test$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  mutate(date=dmy(date),Station=as.factor(Station),time=as.factor(time)) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Station, y = number,fill=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

Comment: Replace `df` with `test`

Answer (score 2):

If you colour the different times it should be the plot you are looking for.

```r
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = factor(Station), y = number, colour = time)) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: You could use fill for colour but it's still ok and very simple. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this very easily without packages, basically like this:

```
# basic
boxplot(number ~ Station + time, data=test[-3], at=c(1, 4, 2, 5),
        xlab="Station", ylab="Number", main="Stations")
```

If you want it colored with legends, you can do:

```
boxplot(number ~ Station + time, data=test[-3], at=c(1, 4, 2, 5), xaxt="n",
        xlab="", ylab="Number", main="Stations", col=rep(cm.colors(2), each=2))
axis(1, at=c(1.5, 4.5), labels=paste("Station", 1:2))
legend("topleft", fill = cm.colors(2), legend = c("Day", "Night"))
```

**Produces**

[image]